# Joining three mysql tables

Tags: mysql, join

If I have three tables:

```
posts
------
postid  date_posted title   content


views
------
viewid  post_id user_id


users
------
userid  username
```

1. What is the correct way of listing all `posts` that have not been viewed by `user_id`? Is this query correct?

   `SELECT * FROM posts LEFT JOIN views ON postid=post_id WHERE user_id=123 AND postid=NULL;`
2. How about listing all `posts` and their "view status" by `user_id`?
3. Can you also recommend a great (user-friendly, non-geeky) resource to improve my understanding of LEFT JOIN, CROSS JOIN, and (normal joins? select * from posts, views)?

Thank you!

Comment: Get a cup of coffee and start reading http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)
Explains a lot and is very helpfull :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.

```
SELECT *
FROM posts
WHERE postid NOT IN (
    SELECT post_id 
    FROM views
    WHERE user_id = 123
)
```

OR

```
SELECT *
FROM posts
LEFT JOIN views ON views.post_id = posts.postid AND views.user_id = 123
WHERE viewid IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: +1, For 1 you have to watch out the `NULL` values in the `post_id` it won't work if there is `NULL` values for `post_id` just add `AND post_id is not null` . Instead you can use `NOT Exists` it safe than `NOT IN` for null values.

Comment: To clarify, the second option is better. The first uses a subquery which should be avoided if possible as they require more time/resources to run.

Answer (score 1):

```
1.select * from posts where post_id in(select post_id from views where user_id<>123)
or
select * from posts p join views v
on p.post_id=v.post_id
and v.user_id<>123

2.select p.*,CASE when isnull(v.viewid,0)=0 then 0 else 1 end as viewstatus
from posts p left join views v
on p.post_id=v.post_id
```

Answer (score 1):

In response to your 3rd question, check the link from [visual-explanation-of-sql-joins from codinghorror.com](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html). This would help you enhance your understading of joins.

Comment: thank you! this is a really good resource for understanding joins.

Answer (score 0):

1, You would need to include the users table too, But that is roughly the correct query yes

2,SELECT * FROM posts LEFT JOIN views ON postid=post_id   should show that it will show all posts

3, http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Answer (score 0):

1) See answer by "scoota269"

2) See your own SQL but remove `AND postid=NULL`

3) http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp